# Can't get UIActivityIndicator to show up while calling pushViewController in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, uiactivityindicatorview, pushviewcontroller

Here is my code...

```
- (void) threadStartAnimating {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    activityIndicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.center=[self tableView].center;
    [[self tableView] addSubview:activityIndicator];

    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(threadStartAnimating) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
    EventController *eventController = [[EventController alloc] init];
    [eventController setEventID:[[lineItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"view_event_button_param"]];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:eventController animated:YES];
}
```

The event controller contains a web service that takes a few seconds to load. The only way I can get the activity indicator to show is if I throw an infinite loop in there... I found a bunch of examples that mentioned putting it in a separate thread but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: So does the `EventController` load stuff from the web service in its `init` method then? Or elsewhere?

Comment: yes, eventControllers viewDidLoad method calls my method loadDataIntoView which calls a webservice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that if you're getting the data in `viewDidLoad` then that method won't be called until after the view is loaded, which is usually during the process of first displaying that view controller. In your case this is during the `pushViewController:animated:` call.

So one way to do what you want might be to swap around these two lines:

```
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:eventController animated:YES];
```

But, in all honesty, I would create a protocol called `EventControllerDelegate`, have a weak reference property to an `id <EventControllerDelegate>` in your `EventController` and then set the view controller which creates the `EventController` as the delegate before you push it. Then define a method in the delegate and implement it in your view controller and in that method stop the spinner. Then in `EventController`, when you've finished loading your data, call the delegate method.

Edit: If you really want to do it without defining a delegate, you could try changing your code to something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    activityIndicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityIndicator.center=[self tableView].center;
    [[self tableView] addSubview:activityIndicator];

    EventController *eventController = [[EventController alloc] init];
    [eventController setEventID:[[lineItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"view_event_button_param"]];

    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIView *v = eventController.view;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [[self navigationController] pushViewController:eventController animated:YES];
        });
    });
}
```

It's using GCD for clarity and the usual "access the view property to force a `loadView` / `viewDidLoad`" hack.

Comment: switching those lines doesn't work. the indicator wont show. maybe cause its not enough time? i was hoping for the simplest solution. a lot of my screens need to load for various reasons and i was hoping to just paste some code in each area that i initialize the next viewController

Comment: Well you can't, really. I really do suggest the delegate way like I showed.

Comment: is there anywhere else i can move the web service code that will allow it to work the way i have it? perhaps viewWillAppear?

Comment: the other issue is that even if i remove the stopAnimation, it doesn't come on. isn't the second thread supposed to trigger that?

Comment: Yes but that's racing like mad because I guess that 2nd thread runs start animating before your main thread then does stop animating. If you want to try something else, see my edit in my answer.

Answer (score -3):

You need to set a frame size for your `activityIndicator`.

```
activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 40, 40);
```

Comment: does not work. i dont think this is necessary as it will show if i throw in an infinite loop